# Multiple Database Search Method Overloads

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, oop

I have a class called Member

```
class Member
{
    // properties to set values
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Address3 { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
    public AccountType accountType;

    public static bool AddNewMember(Member newMember)
    {
        // Code to add member to database here
    }

    public static List<Member> GetAllMembers()
    {
       // code to return all members from the database
       // SQL QUERY: SELECT * FROM Member
    }

    public static List<Member> FindMember(int memberId)
    {
       // code to find member(s) with the member Id
       // SQL QUERY: SELECT * FROM Member WHERE MemberId = memberId
    }

    public static List<Member> FindMember(string memberSurname)
    {
        // code to find members in the database with the given surname
        // SQL QUERY: SELECT * FROM Member WHERE AccountHoldersurname = memberSurname
    }
```

and members are stored in the following database table:

```
CREATE TABLE Member
(
       MemberID                     INT IDENTITY(1,1)            PRIMARY KEY,
       AccountTypeID                INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES AccountTypes (AccountTypeID),
       AccountHolderFirstName       VARCHAR(50),
       AccountHolderSurname         VARCHAR(50),
       AccountHolderAddress1        VARCHAR(50),
       AccountHolderAddress2        VARCHAR(50),
       AccountHolderAddress3        VARCHAR(50),
       AccountHolderPostcode        VARCHAR(10),
       AccountHolderContactNo       VARCHAR(12)
)
```

What I want to do is allow for a list of members to be returned which match a given criteria.

Currently there are two FindMember method overloads which allow for members to be searched by memberId or firstName.

However, I want to the members to be searchable by any of the properties. So this would mean adding another overload for each property as so:

```
public static List<Member> FindMember(string memberFirstname)
{
    // code to find members in the database with the given firstname
}
```

However, I cannot do that as there is already a method overload with the same signature.

Also, I want to allow for Members to be searchable by multiple parameters, EG firstname and surname or Address1 and surname.

I could probably achieve the first requirement (searchable by each individual parameter) by creating a search method as such:

```
public static List<Member> FindMember(string parameterToSearch, string value)
{
    // code to find members in the database with the given surname
}
```

but that would probably mean dynamically building the WHERE clause in the SQL.

What other, simple ways are there to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a single search method instead of one for each combination. Pass in a nullable parameter for each property. Then all you need to do is send those values to a catch all type of procedure and you are done.

Here is an excellent article on how to build this type of query.

http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: Perfect,
Seems obvious now!

Comment: Seems like a lot of work when you can parameterize the calling method as easily as you can the sproc.

See answer below.  Use the enum, use it and your search value as parameters, populate the SqlCommand, job done.

Comment: @RichBryant you still have to write the queries to find the data for any number of data points.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to the members to be searchable by any of the properties. 
>   So this would mean adding another overload for each property

You cannot. Overloading is done using the signature of the methods. If you have the same signature for two methods the code will not compile.

> What other, simple ways are there to achieve this?

Create an method for each search predicate you wan to use.
Combine the predicats into a where clouse (Dynamic or not you should decide) and performe the operation.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a new enum.

```
public enum FieldName 
{
    AccountHolderFirstName,
    AccountHolderSurname,
    AccountHolderAddress1,
    AccountHolderAddress2,
    AccountHolderAddress3,
    AccountHolderPostcode,
    AccountHolderContactNo
}
```

Then create a new class (actually a struct would do, but what the hell).

```
public class SearchCriteria
{
    public FieldName Key {get;set;}
    public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

Then amend your class code.

```
public static List<Member> FindMember(SearchCriteria criteria)
{
    // code to find members in the database with the given criteria
    // SQL QUERY: "SELECT * FROM Member WHERE [" + criteria.Key.ToString() + "] = '" + criteria.Value + "';"
}
```

That's easy enough.

Terrible practice though.  Really you should be extracting all that database code out to a repository, injecting it through ${{your preferred DI container}} and calling that in the appropriate methods.

Have a look at [Insight.Database](https://github.com/jonwagner/Insight.Database) and flip through the Getting Started wiki page.  You'll be amazed.

Comment: That sample sql in here is not a good way to write sql at all. It is wide open to sql injection if you build up a string like that.

Comment: Hence my comment regarding using a repository.

The Sql is fine for a stored procedure with a pair of string parameters and I was reluctant to write the questioner's entire data layer for them.  In fact, I assumed his/her query was merely a mock to give us an idea of how his queries work.  Didn't you?

Comment: Maybe...all I was saying is that your example query is bad example because it is possible to OP may use that pattern in their code.

Comment: It's the OP's query with one minor alteration.  I don't know if you noticed that.

Comment: Just because the OP posted a recipe for sql injection doesn't mean we should continue that. All I was saying is the query posted in your answer is not a good approach. To me it doesn't matter if you wrote it or the OP, the fact is that building up a string and executing it is bad.

Comment: That's why I said it was terrible practice.  *shrug*

In order to make you happy, I appear to have two choices.

1. Write an entire data layer, including a parameterized sproc or 
2. Remove the query and thus the reference to the OP's question.

Neither is convenient, thanks anyway.

Comment: LOL or just don't include that sql and say that the query should be parameterized. :) To be honest your answer sounds like a great application layer method to call the sql code in my answer.

Comment: Since we're chatting, the fieldname stuff is pretty safe since it's taken directly from the enum.  Tell you what, I'll write the query and some basic ADO.NET to call it, thus avoiding a holy war about ORMs.